# Print the row and column numbers of a matrix-python

Tags: python

I am trying to print the row number and column number of a matrix where the value is 1.
For example:

```
A=[0 1 0]
  [1 0 1]
  [1 0 0]
```

I want the output to be displayed as:(row number followed by the corresponding column)

```
0 1
1 0 2
2 0
```

I tried to use enumerate() but it gave me different kind of output.

```
G={i: [j for j, y in enumerate(row) if y] for i, row in enumerate(A)}
print (G)
```

Comment: You know Python's indices are zero-based, yes? And that dictionaries are *unordered*?

Comment: yes sir,i know. I will edit the question

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is? Just printing out a dictionary is *never* going to give the output you want - you will have to do some formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's indices are zero-based. You have done everything correctly, but just need to add a couple of `+1`s to get the output you expected. Also, dictionaries are unordered by nature, so you would be better off just using a list of tuples:

```
G = [(i+1, [j+1 for j, y in enumerate(row) if y]) for i, row in enumerate(A)]
```

---

Or better still; just a 2d list using the indices as the first column when you need them.

Comment: Thank you sir.That did the trick.What if i want to remove all those brackets and commas.I am trying to save this to a file.

Comment: @user3258267 `['{} {}'.format(a, ' '.join(b)) for a, b in G]` gives you a list of strings in that format. Sorry I took a while to reply, my internet suddenly went down.

Comment: When i try that i get an error saying "expected str instance,int found".

Comment: @user3258267 Try `['{} {}'.format(a, ' '.join(map(str, b))) for a, b in G]`. I forgot to cast the indices to strings.